# google play console application refused because of permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions, google-play-console

I want to publish an app for sms and mms backup but google reject it all of the time.

This is the permissions on my manifest file.

```java
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />
```

When I send my app on the google play console, I have a warning 
[image]
I don't want to set my app as the default sms and dialer app.

But I found this on the documentation :

[image]

So I register my app with the label : "Backup and restore transactions for users and archiving for the enterprise (time-limited / discontinuous)"

But my app continues to be rejected and I dont understand why

Comment: It looks like there's a policy allowing only one app at the time to access SMS and it's the app which is registered as the default one for handling SMS to prevent reading and stealing messages in the background. Because of that user is always 100% aware which app can mess with his private messages.
Have you tried other apps like yours? For example https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore AFAIR It does exactly what google requires. Before it can do anything it tells you to set it as the default messages handler and facilitates this process.

Comment: Yes I have already see this app but she don't ask for being the default sms app on the phone. This is why I don't want to ask for it.

Comment: I hope it'll help you for my research without default handler can't request the READ_SMS permission  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/default-handlers#follow-requirements-default-handlers

Comment: Also help this Doc. https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions to use high risk or sensitive permissions like `READ_SMS` -
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102?hl=en